# How to update the Windows 10 version on a custom ISO image

Tags: windows, powershell, iso-image

So my company has a custom Win10 boot image for provisioning new computers. However a new image hasn't been created recently. I am looking for a way to keep all the custom parameters like the PowerShell scripts that run with it, etc. I found there is a way to add update packages, but does it actually update the ISO image to that version of Windows, or does it just run the update package. It take's forever to have to have to update each new computer after imaging them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you need to edit is not an .iso it is boot.wim You should be able to edit the file using after mounting using DISM. The process is here.
[Customize boot images with Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/osd/get-started/customize-boot-images)
You can the place this on a WinPE bootable USB or CD.
This is also may be relevant to you.
[Create a custom Windows PE boot image with Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-cm/create-a-custom-windows-pe-boot-image-with-configuration-manager)